# How to create a decorator with decorator attributes?

Tags: python

I have seen decorators like this, how do I create them?

```
@deco.deco_attribute
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

I know how to create a decorator, that looks something like this

```
import time

def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        time_in = time.time()
        x = func(*args, **kwargs)
        time_out = time.time()
        print(time_out - time_in)
        return x
    return wrapper

@timer
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

and have even seen examples of adding arguments to a decorator, which could be accomplished using
nested functions.

```
def timer(*deco_args):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            time_in = time.time()
            x = func(*args, **kwargs)
            time_out = time.time()
            print(*deco_args, time_out - time_in)
            return x
        return wrapper
    return inner

@timer(2, 3)
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Other variations that I am aware of include, nesting multiple decorators or creating a class as a decorator, or creating a function as a decorator for a class.

But how to create the decorator mentioned on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class and put every decorator inside it

```py
class deco():
  @staticmethod
  def time_1(func):
    def inner():
      return 0 
    return inner

  @staticmethod
  def time_2(func):
    def inner():
      return 0 
    return inner


@deco.time_1
def test():
  return 4+5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its just a matter of how you do the import. In your example you would have only imported the module `import deco` and then accessed the decorator inside that module as you would with any other function. One place I often see the module being imported rather the decorator is pytest fixtures:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
...
```

Comment: but what if I want to do `@timer.attr` in the above example without using any import? Is it possible?